# How is smart contract's hash I'd is made? Is it a random string assigned to a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, evm

How is this contract I'd or hash or whatever is made? For example This is my smart contract "0xBa5C1c9823733d93d05593e3962fa0b8948675D1", is this " 0xBa... " a hash of the code or bytecode?